# Equivalent of uploading files via S3 pre-signed URLs for Azure Blob

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've been trying to migrate a web-app from AWS to Azure. One thing that we do for user uploads is generate pre-signed URLs for S3 in the backend that the frontend can use to upload files via POST requests. Code looks something like this:

```py
import boto3

url = boto3.client('s3').generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='put_object', 
    Params={'Bucket': 'BUCKET_NAME', 'Key': 'OBJECT_KEY'},
    ExpiresIn=3600)
return url
```

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent for Azure's Blob Storage. From the documentation the best I can guess is to use SAS, but that just returns a token. I.e.

```py
from azure.storage.blob import ResourceTypes, AccountSasPermissions, generate_account_sas

sas_token = generate_account_sas(
    "accountname",
    "<secret>",
    resource_types=ResourceTypes(object=True),
    permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True, write=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)
```

How do I convert that into a URL that I can POST a file onto?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple - you simply prepend appropriate URL to get a SAS URL (which is equivalent to a pre-signed URL in AWS S3) and then perform the operation (call the REST API).

To perform operations on the account, you will prepend `https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net` to your SAS token.

To perform operations on a blob container, you will prepend `https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername` to your SAS token.

To perform operations on a blob, you will prepend `https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/blobname` to your SAS token.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code to get a `blob_client` using which you can perform blob related operations. This makes use of `Azure Storage Blobs SDK version 12.8.1`.

```
from azure.storage.blob import ResourceTypes, AccountSasPermissions, generate_account_sas,BlobClient
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

account_name = "account-name"
account_key = "account-key=="
container_name = "test"
blob_name = "blobs.txt"
account_url = "https://" + account_name + "blob.core.windows.net"

sas_token = generate_account_sas(
    account_name,
    account_key,
    resource_types=ResourceTypes(object=True),
    permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True, write=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)

print(sas_token)

sas_url = account_url + "?" + sas_token

print(sas_url)

blob_client = BlobClient(sas_url, container_name, blob_name)

#...now you can call "upload_blob" method to upload the file.
```

Comment: Thanks @gaurav-mantri - this makes a ton of sense. What I'm still trying to wrap my head around is that in S3 you can get a presigned URL that you can make a POST request from a frontend application to upload directly to S3. I.e.
`const postData = new FormData(); postData.append("file", file); await axios.post(signature, postData);`. Can you do that here? I don't want to have to upload a file to our server and then perform an upload to the Container